# Parsing IPv6 address

Tags: haskell

I need to convert IPv6 from string like "fe80::dd99:5d56:cf09:b1ef" to Binary or to (Word64,Word64).  Closest I came to is Network.IP.Addr package, but I'm a newbie and this signature is impenetrable for me:

```
net6Parser :: (CharParsing μ, Monad μ, IsNetAddr n, NetHost n ~ IP6) => μ n
```

Can someone please provide an example how to use it, or recommend any other package?

Comment: `μ n`? Someone really likes their unicode, huh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `network-ip` package appears to use the `textual` type class and its related package.  Looking at that class's documentation, I see mention of an obvious helper `fromString` that sounds good.  A quick test suggests this is what you're looking for:

```
> import Data.Textual
> import Network.IP.Addr
> fromString  "fe80::dd99:5d56:cf09:b1ef" :: Maybe IP6
Just (ip6FromWords 0xfe80 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xdd99 0x5d56 0xcf09 0xb1ef)
```

So that works fine.  Now how do we get those 8 `Word16` values into a couple `Word64`s?  The most efficient way is to use `fromIntegral`, bit shifts, and logical OR.  I'm feeling lazy so lets just serialize it into a bytestring then deserialize it as two Word64s.  No promise that I have the endian right but...

```
> import Data.Binary
> let x = it -- the prior result, the IPv6
> fmap (decode . encode) it :: Maybe (Word64,Word64)
Just (18338657682652659712,15967896581240893935)
```

Answer (score 0):

While Thomas' answer is correct and helpful, I totally forgot there's getAddrInfo standard function and I ended up using its output like:

```
fromSockAddr :: SockAddr -> (Word64, Word64)
fromSockAddr a = case a of
               -- SockAddrInet pn ha (IPV4 not needed)
               SockAddrInet6 pn fi ha sid -> decode $ encode ha :: (Word64,Word64)
```